# Formula for cosmic variance

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

I was reading this page: [Sample and Cosmic Variance](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept05/Gawiser2/Gawiser4.html). The section states that

> The multipoles $C_\ell$ can be related to the expected value of the
>   spherical harmonic coefficients by
>   $$ \Bigg\langle
> \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a^2_{\ell m}\Bigg\rangle = (2\ell+1)C_\ell
> $$
>   since there are $(2\ell + 1)$ $a_{\ell m}$ for each $\ell$ and each
>   has an expected autocorrelation of $C_\ell$. In a theory such as
>   inflation, the temperature fluctuations follow a Gaussian distribution
>   about these expected ensemble averages. This makes the $a_{\ell m}$
>   Gaussian random variables, resulting in a $\chi^2_{2\ell+1}$
>   distribution for $\sum_m a_{\ell m}^2$. The width of this distribution
>   leads to a cosmic variance in the estimated $C_{\ell}$ of
>   $$
> \bigg(\frac{\Delta
> C_\ell}{C_\ell}\bigg)_\mathrm{cosmic\,variance}=\;\sqrt{\frac{2}{2\ell+1}}
> $$

I don't get how the cosmic variance is derived. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3):

The key statement is that the $a_{\ell,m}$ are *independent* Gaussian random variables.  For each $\ell$, there are $2\ell+1$ of them.  So their sum is, essentially by definition, a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $2\ell+1$ degrees of freedom.  Now, it is a known fact that the variance of a chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is just $2k$, so the variance of $\sum_m a_{\ell,m}^2$ is therefore $2(2\ell+1)$.  This is a basic result from statistics, and you should be able to find a derivation in any textbook.

Comment: Thank you, but where does the square root come from?

Comment: Well, your notation is a little unclear, so I can't say precisely, but basically it comes from the normalization that you have to do to get this result.  If you look at the standard normal distribution, there's a $1/\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}$ out front to normalize it.  This would seem to result in something like your last expression, but I don't know exactly what you mean by $\Delta C_\ell$.

Comment: @Mike : Does the expression $\bigg(\frac{\Delta
C_\ell}{C_\ell}\bigg)_\mathrm{cosmic\,variance}$ refer simply to the standard deviation of Cosmic variance ? (but under the form of a relative error ?)